# How siblings can I remove elements that make?

Tags: jquery

When I clicked on the gold it is made of only one element, and
Click on the silver or unlimited in time and remove the previous element that was clicked elements displayed.
Like the Lenovo download site drivers.

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/7H2pL/20/)

[youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHDAS19-Y2E&feature=youtu.be)

```
$(function () {

        var groupTypes = null;

        var count = 0;

        $.getJSON('/api/Groups', null, function (data) {
            groupTypes = data;
            var $list = $('<ol id="selectable" />');

            $.each(groupTypes, function (i, groupType) {
                var $li = $('<li />');
                $li
                    .addClass('ui-widget-content')
                    .attr('data-index', i)
                    .html(groupType.Name);

                $list.append($li);

                $li.on('click', function () {
                    count++;
                    var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
                    $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('ui-selected');
                    $(this).addClass('ui-selected');

                    var speeds = groupTypes[index].GroupSpeeds;
                    console.log(speeds);
                    var $speedList = $('<ol id="selectable" />');
                    $.each(speeds, function (i, speed) {
                        if (speed) {
                            var $speedLi = $('<li />');
                            $speedLi
                                .addClass('ui-widget-content')
                                .attr('data-index', i)
                                .html(speed.Speed);

                            $speedList.append($speedLi);
                            $(this).parent('#container').nextAll().remove();

                        }
                    });

                    $('body').append($speedList);
                });
            });

            $('#container').append($list);
        });
```

Comment: provided jsFiddle is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add special class for elements that you append

```
$speedLi.addClass('speed')
```

and then remove them before you append more

```
$('.speed').remove()
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vgPkU/

Comment: +1 Pretty much got the same outcome as me http://jsfiddle.net/vBF3T/2/ No need for another answer =)